# How to use function in class methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a `calculator` class. and this has following methods, `getInputFields` and `sum`.

```
const addBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("add") as HTMLButtonElement;;
const subBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("subtract") as HTMLButtonElement;
const multiplyBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("multiply") as HTMLButtonElement;
const divideBtn: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("divide") as HTMLButtonElement;

class Calculator {

    result: HTMLSpanElement;
    inputOne: HTMLInputElement;
    inputTwo: HTMLInputElement;
    numOne:number;
    numTwo:number;

    constructor() {
        this.result = document.getElementById("result") as HTMLSpanElement;
        this.inputOne = document.getElementById("num1") as HTMLInputElement;
        this.inputTwo = document.getElementById("num2") as HTMLInputElement;
    }

    getInputFields() {
        this.inputOne = document.getElementById("num1") as HTMLInputElement;
        this.inputTwo = document.getElementById("num2") as HTMLInputElement;
        this.numOne = parseInt(this.inputOne.value);
        this.numTwo = parseInt(this.inputTwo.value);
    }

    sum() {
        this.getInputFields();
        if (!isNaN(this.numOne) && !isNaN(this.numTwo)) {
            this.result.textContent = (this.numOne + this.numTwo).toString();
        }
    }
```

Below the above code, I use addEventListener to run sum method.

```
const calculator = new Calculator();
addBtn.addEventListener('click', calculator.sum);
```

You can see `this.getInputFields` is inside `sum()` method. Why do I have that inside sum method?
Because I want to make subtract, multiplication, division methods.
But I don't want to repeat the same codes to assign `document.getElmentById("num1") as HTMLInputElement` in every method.

That's why I put that code into `getInputFields`.
But this doesn't work inside class methods..

Here's error I got,

```
main.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: this.getInputFields is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.Calculator.sum (main.js:20)
```

Comment: The value of “this” changes inside the event listener callback. Bind the class methods to “this” in the constructor

Comment: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is in the usage of the `this` keyword.
In other languages, like C#, passing a class method around will keep it "linked" to it's originating component. Not in JavaScript (and, by extension, TypeScript).

In JavaScript the `this` keyword is *bound* at execution time.
So, if you call `calculator.sum()` `this` in `sum` will be bound to `calculator`, but if you do:

```
const func = calculator.sum;
func(); // <- inside this call, this is the global object (window)
```

Basically, when there is no `object.` in front of a call, this is implicitly bound to the global object (window, in case of browsers).

In your case, you could simply replace the line:

```
addBtn.addEventListener('click', calculator.sum);
```

with:

```
addBtn.addEventListener('click', (_clickEvent) => calculator.sum());
// or
addBtn.addEventListener('click', calculator.sum.bind(calculator));
```

Refer to the excellent answers linked by @Thomas in [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for many more examples regarding your question.